# how to fix : Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component Next.js || onScroll event

Tags: next.js, use-state, onscroll

here the code

```
const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
     setScroll(window.scrollY > specify_height_you_want_to_change_after_here);
   });
 }, []);
```

get this error

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove your event listener in the useEffect cleanup function. This function runs when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    setScroll(window.scrollY > specify_height_you_want_to_change_after_here);
  });

  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", () => {
    setScroll(window.scrollY > specify_height_you_want_to_change_after_here);
  });
}, []);
```

To make your code more readable, you might want to separate the listener to a separate function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const scrollListener = () => {
    setScroll(window.scrollY > specify_height_you_want_to_change_after_here);
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollListener);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);
}, []);
```

Comment: still gives same error on cleanup `return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);`